# Difference between private EventHandler and private event EventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, event-handling

Basically what the title says.
Whats the difference between those two (I am currently using the first one)

```
private EventHandler _progressEvent;
```

and

```
private event EventHandler _progressEvent;
```

I have a method

```
void Download(string url, EventHandler progressEvent) {
    doDownload(url)
    this._progressEvent = progressEvent;
}
```

The doDownload method would call the

```
_progressEvent(this, new EventArgs());
```

It works fine, so far. But I feel I am doing something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first defines a delegate, the second defines an event.  The two are related, but they're typically used very differently.

In general, if you're using `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<T>`, this would suggest that you're using an event.  The caller (for handling progress) would typically *subscribe* to the event (not pass in a delegate), and you'd raise the event if you have subscribers.

If you want to use a more functional approach, and pass in a delegate, I would choose a more appropriate delegate to use.  In this case, you're not really providing any information in the `EventArgs`, so perhaps just using `System.Action` would be more appropriate.

That being said, an event approach appears more appropriate here, from the little code shown.  For details on using events, see [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) in the C# Programming Guide.

Your code, using events, would likely look something like:

```
// This might make more sense as a delegate with progress information - ie: percent done?
public event EventHandler ProgressChanged;

public void Download(string url)
{ 
  // ... No delegate here...
```

When you call your progress, you'd write:

```
var handler = this.ProgressChanged;
if (handler != null)
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The user of this would write this as:

```
yourClass.ProgressChanged += myHandler;
yourClass.Download(url);
```

Comment: I guess I don't really need real events, because I will only have 1 subscriber and I need to pass the delegates around. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

For `private`, there is no difference between the two, but for `public` you would want to use `event`.

The event keyword is an access modifier like private internal and protected.
It is used for restricting access to multicast delegates. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event

Going from most visible to least visible we have

```
public EventHandler _progressEvent;
//can be assigned to from outside the class (using = and multicast using +=)
//can be invoked from outside the class 

public event EventHandler _progressEvent;
//can be bound to from outside the class (using +=), but can't be assigned (using =)
//can only be invoked from inside the class

private EventHandler _progressEvent;
//can be bound from inside the class (using = or +=)
//can be invoked inside the class  

private event EventHandler _progressEvent;
//Same as private. given event restricts the use of the delegate from outside
// the class - i don't see how private is different to private event
```

Comment: Be carefull! there is an important distinction in thread safety of subscription. See e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wo4lTd

Comment: This is a better answer in my opinion.